# Signature of a Python CFFI Function?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I am wrapping a number of libraries using the `cffi` Python module.  I am writing mock libraries for them, and I want to determine if a particular invocation of a cffi wrapped function will result in an error due to call signature mismatches.

I am roughly trying to write the call `is_call_valid` below:

```
import cffi

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef("int strlen(char *string)")
lib = ffi.dlopen()

is_call_valid(call=lib.strlen, args=(b"asd",))
is_call_valid(call=lib.strlen, args=(1,))
```

Comment: Try ``ffi.typeof(lib.strlen).args``.

Comment: That gets you the string name of the arguments, not whether all the arguments can be cohered to them.

Comment: No?  I get ``(<ctype 'char *'>,)`` in the example above.